# smoothly move object on mouse drag using lerp

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

This is the code to move my object using lerp and mouseDrag event but it is not working very smoothly.

```
//Camera Point smooth movment 
if (mouseWorking)
{
   if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit, Camera.main.farClipPlane)) //,LayerMask.NameToLayer("Gola")))
   {
      if (hit.transform.gameObject.name == "CameraElasticPoint")
      {
         return;
      }
      else
      {
         //working
         transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(transform.position, new Vector3(hit.point.x, hit.point.y + 1, hit.point.z), Time.deltaTime * 3); //0.5000001f

         //StartCoroutine(SmoothMove());
         hitPoint = Input.mousePosition;
       }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You may find [Vector's Lerp](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.Lerp.html) to be smoother.

```
public class ExampleClass : MonoBehaviour {
    public Transform startMarker;
    public Transform endMarker;
    public float speed = 1.0F;
    private float startTime;
    private float journeyLength;
    void Start() {
        startTime = Time.time;
        journeyLength = Vector3.Distance(startMarker.position, endMarker.position);
    }
    void Update() {
        float distCovered = (Time.time - startTime) * speed;
        float fracJourney = distCovered / journeyLength;
        transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(startMarker.position, endMarker.position, fracJourney);
    }
}
```

Comment: it about rotation while i am moving the object

Comment: @MohammadFaizanKhan Sorry, yeah. Updated to a link from Unity's docs with a good way to implement this.

Comment: If you look at their documentation, they offer a Start/Update technique which adds a smoothing factor, I'll update the comment for visibility.

Comment: @MohammadFaizanKhan Did my answer help you solve your issue?

Comment: no it didn't work jumping jumping jumping, no smoothness